# ZipEntry unknown size although set

Tags: java, zip, size

I searched and read all questions about ZipEntry (JAVA 7) but my problem is nowhere addressed:

I successfully zip and unzip files in JAVA, but although, at zip time, I set the uncompressed size by `ZipEntry.setSize(long)` to values surely smaller than int value,
reading back, at unzip time, by `ZipEntry.getSize()` always returns -1.
Although my programs run well, the verification part warns for `unknown size`.

How do I set the uncompressed size?

Comment: Code fragment: // File f, zip name in 's', length = f.length()
               entry = new ZipEntry(s);
               System.out.println(s); // DEBUG
               entry.setSize(length);
               System.out.println(length); // DEBUG
               entry.setTime(f.lastModified());
               
               operation = "WRITING ZIP-ENTRY";
               zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry);
Output:     ScreenShotW7.png
80120

Comment: Sorry, that looks ugly.

Answer (score 3):

At first sight it looks like a bug, but as explained [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6491622) it's actually not!

The size information (along with some other info like CRC) is stored compressed so to get access to this information you have to:

1. First call `getNextEntry()` to get the first entry
2. Right now calling `getSize()` will return -1
3. Read the data of the file by calling `read(buffer)`
4. Call `getNextEntry()` again
5. At this point calling `getSize()` on the **first** entry will now return the correct size!

Weird, but that's how it apparently is supposed to work

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, I'm gonna try this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a bug in JAVA:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2073587?start=0&tstart=0

For the moment I could not find anything of a solution or a mending yet.
Probably ORACLE thinks: the unzip works, so leave it alone.
Greetings.
;JOOP!